# How can I get the Array field of a class with reflection?

Tags: java, arrays, reflection

My class A has

```
   AClaz[] rofl;
```

The documentation for getDeclaredFields says "This method returns an array of length 0 if the class or interface declares no fields, or if this Class object represents a primitive type, **an array class,** or void. "

I want to access the rofl array of type AClaz using reflection. Even if the AClaz is an inner class of class A.

So I would do getDeclaredClass ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're misreading the documentation - it's talking about calling `getDeclaredFields` *on* an array class, like this:

```
Class<?> arrayClass = String[].getClass();
Field[] fields = arrayClass.getDeclaredFields();
```

You should be able to get the field from `A` without any problem using

```
Field[] fields = A.class.getDeclaredFields();
```

and then iterate over the array, or

```
Field roflField = A.class.getDeclaredField("rofl");
```

The fact that the *field* type is an array is not a problem at all.

Comment: Aha I see! And it works even when the roflField array type is of an inner class? At least to read its values? Could I do roflField.get(instance).doAclazMethod() ?

Comment: @AntonioP: No, because `roflField.get()` returns `Object`. You'd need to cast to the right type (`Aclaz[]`) and then select an element from it. For example: `Aclaz[] values = (Aclaz[]) field.get(instance); values[0].doSomething();`

Answer (score 1):

`getDeclaredFields()` returns all fields, i.e. instances of class `Field`. You want to access one of the fields named `rofl`, so you can either iterate over array returned by `getDeclaredFields()` or use `getDeclaredField("rofl")`. Then, once you have instance of Field you can access the field value itself using `set()` and `get()`. If you want to set the value you have to provide value of correct type, i.e. array of AClaz.

If you want to change one element of existing array stored in field rofl in your class you should say something like this: `Array.set(field.get(instance), index, element)`

Answer (score 0):

you can get fields like this...

```
Class<?> arrayClass = String[].getClass();
Field[] fields =  arrayClass.getDeclaredFields();
for(int i =0; i<fields.length; i++){

  if(fields[i].isArray()){
//array type fields can be checked like this
    fields[i] is array
  }
}
```